# webpack reactjs app fails to load: Uncaught ReferenceError: snapapp is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

This is a minimal reactjs application which, when bundled using webpack and then run, gives the following error from the browser console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: snapapp is not defined
```

Can anyone suggest why?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body class='section'>
<div id="app"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./build/snapapp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var mountNode = document.getElementById('app');
        snapapp.start(mountNode);
    })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import rootLayout from './src/components/ApplicationLayout.jsx';
import hello from './src/components/hello.jsx';
export function start(mountNode) {
  render(<rootLayout />, mountNode);
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    path: 'build',
    filename: 'snapapp.js',
    libraryTarget: "umd"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

src/components/hello.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello</h1>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are exporting snapapp from your module, but you aren't importing/requiring it anywhere, it doesn't exist as a global variable.

Comment: I'm giving away my noob status with JavaScript here, but from where would I import it?  What does such an import look like?

Comment: The easiest way to get it to work is instead of exporting a function from index.js, just initialise it in there rather than in your HTML. In terms of importing, in another JS file, ie `Main.js`, you'd import with either `import snapapp from './index';` or `var snapapp = require('./index');`

Comment: Hmmm...  snapapp.js IS index.js - it's the result of webpack bundling index.js, so I wouldn't be able to load it from there.

Comment: Yeah, I was giving you an example of how to import. It should work if you change index.js to:
`import { render } from 'react-dom';`
`import rootLayout from './src/components/ApplicationLayout.jsx';`
`import hello from './src/components/hello.jsx';`

`render(<rootLayout />, document.getElementById('app'));`

Answer (score 0):

You are exporting as a UMD file format.  If you need to inline code within your index.html file then you will need to either use a library like [Require](http://requirejs.org/)

Alternative you can:

**Output to var**

Change `umd` to `var`, you can read about [it here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-librarytarget), this will add your library onto the `window` global object.  Allowing you to call it like you are within your html file.

```
output: {
    path: 'build',
    filename: 'snapapp.js',
    libraryTarget: "var"
}
```

**Place your bootup script into your file bundle**

Unless there is some special reason I would move the bootup script into your index.js file.  There is no reason you can not get the mount point from within the file.  This also a very common pattern for what you are trying to do.

```
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import rootLayout from './src/components/ApplicationLayout.jsx';
import hello from './src/components/hello.jsx';

render(<rootLayout />, document.getElementById('app'));
```